# 215 error while requesting Token from Twitter oAuth API

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to Implement Twitter login in my NodeJS app.

As per the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/request_token) from Twitter, I need to pass the below parameters to this url via POST request. 
**URL:**

`https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token`

**PARAMETERS:**

```
 oauth_nonce=, 
 oauth_signature=, 
 oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%3A3005%2Ftwitter%2Fprocess_callback", 
 oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",       
 oauth_timestamp="currentTimestamp", 
 oauth_consumer_key=“myKEY”, 
 oauth_version="1.0"
```

I'm passing a random string for `oauth_nonce` parameter. I'm not clear on how to create a `oauth_signature`?

I keep getting 215 error whenever I make the POST request beacuse of incorrect `oauth_nonce` and `oauth_signature` values I guess.

How do I generate `oauth_nonce` and `oauth_signature` values while making the request in NodeJS.

Comment: no progress up till now?

Answer (score 5):

Those parameters need to be passed in your authorization header:

```
OAuth oauth_nonce="K7ny27JTpKVsTgdyLdDfmQQWVLERj2zAK5BslRsqyw", 
oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%3A3005%2Ftwitter%2Fprocess_callback", 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
oauth_timestamp="1300228849", 
oauth_consumer_key="OqEqJeafRSF11jBMStrZz", 
oauth_signature="Pc%2BMLdv028fxCErFyi8KXFM%2BddU%3D", 
oauth_version="1.0"
```

But before that, you need to get a signature, **which will then give you all of the parameters above**. Check [the documentation here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html).

A recommendation would be to use a 3rd party library like [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport), which heavily simplifies this process if needed.

Comment: Sure, [here is a link to the respective documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/twitter/)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

> How do I generate oauth_nonce and oauth_signature values while making the request in NodeJS.

Going through these post will be of help to you [Creating a signature](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html) and [How to generate an OAuth nonce](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-generate-an-oauth-nonce/1307).

Twitter makes a whole lot of sense if used correctly. I have seen some tutorials that has been quite useful to those around me, that I feel maybe you might want to check [Node Authentication: Twitter](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-twitter) and [Implementing Sign in with Twitter for Node.js](https://www.codementor.io/chrisharrington/how-to-implement-twitter-sign-expressjs-oauth-du107vbhy)

Or you might want to check [passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/twitter/)

You will have to install it in your project by running:
`npm install passport-twitter`

#### Configuration

```
const passport = require('passport')
  , TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;

passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/twitter/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate(..., function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

This [Github](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter) repo might be a great reference to you.

If you're using reactjs, this ([npm i react-twitter-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-twitter-auth)) might be useful to you too.

Answer (score 0):

can't comment, that's why answering here.
the [docu](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request) sais, `oauth_nonce`:

> is a unique token your application should generate for each unique request

it is like the salt of the encryption. you can find `oauth_signature` under the same link. how to generate it is described [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could get Access Token using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-twitter-api) library